# ContourPlot with parameter

Tags: plotting, complex

I have an equation for function `F[x,y]==0` which first argument  `x` is real and another,  `y`, is complex. All constants in equation are real.

I define `y` as `y=a+I*b`.

I need to plot `Im[y]` as function of `x`. (in other words, I need a plot of `b` as function of `x`. The equality for `F` for `a` and `b` and `x` can be solved only using `FindRoot` function.

Here's how I tried to plot what I need:

```
ContourPlot[{{Im[F] == 0, Re[F] == 0}}, {b, 0.1, 
  10^8}, {x, 0.1, 10^16}]
```

But nothing is plotted. Any ideas?
Thank you for help!

---

Here is the function and constants:

```
e2 = 5
e3 = 1
omega1 = 1.1242*10^(16)
omega2 = 4.5896*10^(15)
omega3 = 5.5927*10^(15)
e1 = 1 - omega1^2/x^2
c = 3*10^8
k1 = Sqrt[y^2 - x^2/c^2 e1]
k2 = Sqrt[y^2 - x^2/c^2 e2]
k3 = Sqrt[y^2 - x^2/c^2 e3]
h = 5*10^(-9)
y = a + I b
F = ((k2/e2 + k1/e1)*(k3/e3 + k2/e2))/((k1/e1 - k2/e2)*(k3/e3 - 
       k2/e2)) - Exp[-2 k2 h]
```

Here is my attemption to plot roots I that I tried with FindRoot. But I am not sure it plots all roots correctly and I don't even know where to search for them:

```
 findPoint[i_] := 
 Evaluate[Function[
   Assuming[a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals, 
    FindRoot[{(Re[F] /. x -> (10000*i)) == 
       0, (Im[F] /. x -> (10000*i)) == 0}, {{a, 0.5}, {b, 0.2}}]]]]
list1 := Table[b /. findPoint[i][[1]], {i, 1, 2000}]
list2 := Table[10000*i, {i, 1, 2000}]
PointDone := Inner[List, list1, list2, List]
Show[{Graphics[Point[PointDone], Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameTicksStyle -> 18]}]
```

Here is a plot I got..

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry! I confused letters and there was a mistake.
I edited post, and now it seems to be correct. Thank you!

Comment: Please show your FindRoot usage

Comment: Now showed, @belisarius :)

Comment: You pasted a piece of code without checking if it really runs.

Comment: @belisarius, I'm sorry again. I used small `f` notation, and forgot that in post I used big `'F'`. Now everything should work.

Comment: You should copy your question's code back into Mathematica and test it in a fresh session. That way you'll get more and better answers (and frustrate less users)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide a value for `a` you will get a plot:

```
Block[{a = 10^7}, ContourPlot[{Re[F] == 0, Im[F] == 0}, {b, 0.1, 10^8}, {x, 0.1, 10^16}]]
```

[image]

You could also do a 3D contour plot including `a` as one of the axes:

```
ContourPlot3D[{Re[F] == 0, Im[F] == 0}, {a, 0, 10^8}, {b, 0.1, 10^8}, {x, 0.1, 10^16}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Red], Opacity[0.5, Green]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Here's one way to get a plot of $b$ versus $x$. Looking at the first `ContourPlot` we can see that there's a root near $y = 10^7 + 3 \times 10^7 i$ for $x = 8 \times 10^{15}$. Using that root as a starting point, we can slowly increase (or decrease) $x$, at each step using the previous root as the initial estimate in `FindRoot`.

First restart the kernel and run the initialization code again, but *without* setting `y = a + I b`. The following code then creates a list of `{x,y}` values where `y` is the complex root of `F[x,y]`.

```
root[x1_, rootestimate_] := {x1, y /. FindRoot[F /. x -> x1, {y, rootestimate}]}

start = root[8*10^15, 10^7 + 3*10^7 I];

dataleft = With[{xstep = -10^14}, NestList[root[#[[1]] + xstep, #[[2]]] &, start, 50]];   
dataright = With[{xstep = +10^14}, NestList[root[#[[1]] + xstep, #[[2]]] &, start, 50]];   
alldata = Sort@Join[dataleft, dataright];
```

The plot of `Im[y]` against `x` is then:

```
ListLinePlot[{#1, Im[#2]} & @@@ alldata]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! But when I fix a I get not whole b[x] but only one point in 2D case(the intersection of curves). The 3D case is nothing like I need to obtain.